# Specifying a relative source directory

Tags: sbt, deprecated

I have just recently forked an outdated SBT project (which you can find here https://github.com/mdedetrich/sbt-bower) that was last working with an outdated version of SBT 0.11.0. I am trying to get the sbt plugin to work with SBT versions 0.12.3 and 0.13.0, however I am getting an issue on this line

https://github.com/mdedetrich/sbt-bower/blob/master/src/main/scala/SbtBowerPlugin.scala#L37

When I run `sbt compile`, I get the following error

```
[error] /Users/mdedetrich/github/sbt-bower/src/main/scala/SbtBowerPlugin.scala:37: value / is not a member of java.io.File
[error]     sourceDirectory in Bower <<= (sourceDirectory).apply (_ / "main" / "webapp" )
```

Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I guess the error is because you're `apply`'ing `/` to `java.io.File` that comes out of `sourceDirectory`.

Comment: Yes well I know what is happening, and the / is designed to do relative directory mapping

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mark Harrah, this is actually due to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/0k1No2kfvm8/discussion

I had to remove the `import Path._` in the SbtBowerPlugin.scala file and it now compiles fine!

Comment: Approve the answer if that really answers the question.

Comment: You have to wait 24 hours before approving an answer you make, I have 8 hours left ;)